# Confluence on Tomcat can't start app

Tags: java, tomcat5.5, confluence

I'm trying to get [Confluence](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Installing+Confluence+EAR-WAR+on+Tomcat) wiki running on my Debian box inside Tomcat.  Now, I've never used Tomcat before so I really don't understand a lot of it.  Here's my setup:

```
Debian Lenny 5.0
Tomcat 5.5.26-5
Open jdk openjdk-6-jre
```

all installed with apt

Tomcat itself works and I can view the admin and manager screens, but when I try to start the confluence app, the logs say:

```
Oct 6, 2009 1:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 6, 2009 1:00:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/confluence] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Great help :(

I have in my /var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/Catalina/localhost directory a file named confluence.xml with the following

```
<Context path="/confluence" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/atlassian/confluence-3.0.1/confluence" debug="0" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

and the confluence dir as specified in that context.  Tomcat sees it in the manager, but can't start it.
My server.xml contains the following connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Which I think is pretty standard.  My question is, why can't I see any more info in the logs? How can I get a more specific logging for this app.  The Tomcat docs say that a Logger directive inside this context is no longer valid.  but telling me "because of previous errors" doesn't really help.  Also, if anyone has any tips on setting up Confluence, I'm all ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed to set TOMCAT5_SECURITY=no in the /etc/init.d/tomcat55 file.  In face I had done this, but I also noticed in etc/default/tomcat55 that I had uncommented out the TOMCAT5_SECURITY=yes, so it was being set.  This causes file perm issues when jira is trying to load

Answer (score 0):

FYI openjdk is not officially supported: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-16431

Comment: this should be a comment.